# How to add back and refresh button to PWA title bar

Tags: progressive-web-apps, quasar-framework

I'm writing a PWA app. What I want is `back` and `refresh` button on title bar. But I got nothing.

Update: the buttons should be controlled by browser, not my UI.

Comment: just add them to your header. Detect when you are full screen and add them to your layout. I normally add a back button to my mobile layouts to facilitate going back. Never needed a page refresh. but interesting thought.

Comment: @ChrisLove What I mean is the default buttons added by browser. See [these pictures](https://twitter.com/cn_winwin_2011/status/1309362635666718720?s=20)

Comment: If you use fullscreen for an installed PWA then those buttons are not displaed as none of the Browser chrome is used. Instead you will need to create navigation affordance in your application's UI to handle those needs.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `display` property in the manifest file must be either `fullscreen` or `standalone`. In both cases, the back and refresh buttons won't be shown.

Set the `display` property as `minimal-ui` or `browser`, the back and refresh button will be shown.

Note: Clear cache/Uninstall the PWA for changes to take place.

Comment: Finally I set display as "minimal-ui". Thanks bro!