# How to add Buttons in Title Bar in PWA (Web Apps)

Tags: user-interface, browser, web-applications, progressive-web-apps

How do I add these buttons (`Back` and `Refresh`) in PWA?
Note: I am not looking to add these buttons in my UI. it's in the title bar, which is controlled by browser.

[image: OneDrive PWA]

Comment: hi, may be of interest https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64058232/how-to-add-back-and-refresh-button-to-pwa-title-bar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In manifest.json. Update the display property like this

```
"display": "minimal-ui",
```

Earlier it could have been `standalone`.